# How to get data whose category's parent category status is active only?

Tags: laravel

I have a **Service_Categories** table and the structure of that table is:

|  | Category Title | parent_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first category | null | inactive |
| 2 | first child category | 1 | active |
| 3 | first child child category | 2 | active |

And I have a **Service Table**:

|  | Service Title | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First Service | 3 |
| 2 | Second Service | 1 |

**MODEL**

```
    public function getAllServices() {
        $services = Service::with(['serviceCategory','serviceCategory.parents'])
            ->where('status',true)
            ->whereHas('serviceCategory',function($q) {
                return $q->where('status',true)
                    ->whereHas('serviceCategory.parents',
                    function($parentQuery) {
                        return $parentQuery->where('status, true);
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to say here is that if the top-level category is inactive then, services should not be shown in the collection whose category's parents are inactive.

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I am getting all the services in collection regardless of category status and category's parent status

Comment: is your `status` value `true` or `active`?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your second `whereHas` to the root, as the relation in there is related to service, not the relation inside of it...

```php
public function getAllServices()
{
    $services = Service::with(['serviceCategory', 'serviceCategory.parents'])
        ->where('status', true)
        ->whereHas('serviceCategory', function ($q) {
            return $q->where('status', true);
        })
        ->whereHas('serviceCategory.parents', function ($parentQuery) {
            return $parentQuery->where('status', true);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your status column is not of type Boolean but why are you checking for *** `status=true`*** instead of ***`status="active"`?***
You can not use Boolean to find string.